# 1 application with 2 login security

Tags: symfony

I have an symfony 3 application. There is one part for /api and one /back (administration)

The /api use LexikJwtAuthentication and /back FosUserBundle.

With my actual security, i have an error when i go to /back.

```
A Token was not found in the TokenStorage.
```

I think, my app try to read the Bearer token.

How can i use the FosUSerBundle security with the routes /back ?

My security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

...
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
...
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - api.jwt_authenticator
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

        back:
          pattern:   ^/back
          form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /back/login
            check_path: /back/login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
```

routing.yml

```
fos_user_security_login:
    defaults: { _controller: "FOSUserBundle:Security:login" }
    path: /back/login

fos_user_security_check:
    defaults: { _controller: "FOSUserBundle:Security:check" }
    path: /back/login_check

fos_user_security_logout:
    defaults: { _controller: "FOSUserBundle:Security:logout" }
    path: /back/logout
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: back
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "test@test.test"
        sender_name: "test@test.test"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the provider and the csrf_token_generator like this ([Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-4-configure-your-application-s-security-yml)) :

```
back:
      pattern:   ^/back
      form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        login_path: /back/login
        check_path: /back/login_check
```

And **check if the FOSUser routes are behind /back routes** (cf [Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files) )

Comment: I edit my message with  "csrf_token_generator" and i add my routing.yml. I still have the error.

Comment: Did you add the "provider" ? provider : fos_userbundle

Comment: I talk about the provider in the back firewall. Below form_login.

Comment: If you just active the back firewall did he works ? Comment your twice api firewall to test

Comment: If i comment, that change anything oO. Still have the error

Comment: Did you cache clear ? I think you should try to make the back firewall works first !